# SQL Server 2008 R2 User Permissions

Tags: sql-server-2008, permissions, certificate, symmetric-key

I have a user whose role is **db_datareader** that needs to be able to execute a stored procedure which decrypts some data using our symmetric key and certificate.  I've granted **EXECUTE** perms on the stored procedure itself for this user, but now it wants access to the symmetric key and certificate.  I'm not sure how to grant perms for the key and the certificate while still keeping this user in a **SELECT** or **read-only** mode.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the header of your stored procedure use `WITH EXECUTE AS 'somePrincipal'`, where `somePrincipal` has the necessary permissions to access the symmetric key and certificate.

Comment: So by header you mean `ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SomeStoredProc] WITH EXECUTE AS [somePrincipal]`?

Comment: @Scott yes, just put `WITH EXECUTE AS SELF` if you have permissions against those security objects.  When that SP is executed then, it will execute as the context of your login/user.  Make sense?